# How can i get attribute number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use BS4 to parser .xml，i want to get `res`attribute  number，but get none
how to do it ?

**source xml**

```
 `<digitizer id="1" integrated="true" csrmusttouch="falsehardprox="true" 
    physidcsrs="false"  pnpid="49154" kind="MULTI_TOUCH" maxcsrs="10">      
   <monitor left="0" top="0" right="1920" bottom="1080" />`     
     <properties>          
    <property name="x" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="621.7457275" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010030" guid="{598A6A8F-52C0-4BA0-93AF-AF357411A561}" />

    <property name="y" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="983.9639893" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010031" guid="{B53F9F75-04E0-4498-A7EE-C30DBB5A9011}" />

    <property name="status" logmin="0" logmax="15" res="0" unit="DEFAULT" hidusage="0x000d0042, 0x000d003c, 0x000d0044" guid="{6E0E07BF-AFE7-4CF7-87D1-AF6446208418}" />

    <property name="time" logmin="0" logmax="2147483647" res="1" unit="DEFAULT" guid="{436510C5-FED3-45D1-8B76-71D3EA7A829D}" />

    <property name="contactid" logmin="0" logmax="31" res="1.861861944" unit="cm" hidusage="0x000d0051" guid="{02585B91-049B-4750-9615-DF8948AB3C9C}" />`
```

**Python Code**

```
a = data_xml.find('digitizer',id="1")
b = a.find('properties')
print(b.get('res'))
```

**Result**

None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your data as `html`

```
html="""<digitizer id="1" integrated="true" csrmusttouch="falsehardprox="true" 
    physidcsrs="false"  pnpid="49154" kind="MULTI_TOUCH" maxcsrs="10">      
   <monitor left="0" top="0" right="1920" bottom="1080" />`     
     <properties>          
    <property name="x" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="621.7457275" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010030" guid="{598A6A8F-52C0-4BA0-93AF-AF357411A561}" />

    <property name="y" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="983.9639893" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010031" guid="{B53F9F75-04E0-4498-A7EE-C30DBB5A9011}" />

    <property name="status" logmin="0" logmax="15" res="0" unit="DEFAULT" hidusage="0x000d0042, 0x000d003c, 0x000d0044" guid="{6E0E07BF-AFE7-4CF7-87D1-AF6446208418}" />

    <property name="time" logmin="0" logmax="2147483647" res="1" unit="DEFAULT" guid="{436510C5-FED3-45D1-8B76-71D3EA7A829D}" />

    <property name="contactid" logmin="0" logmax="31" res="1.861861944" unit="cm" hidusage="0x000d0051" guid="{02585B91-049B-4750-9615-DF8948AB3C9C}" />"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
```

Code::

You can find all `property` tag and then find `res` value associate to it!

```
a = soup.find('digitizer',attrs={"id":"1"})
properties=a.find_all("property")
res_lst=[i['res'] for i in properties]
```

Output::

```
['621.7457275', '983.9639893', '0', '1', '1.861861944']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml seems poorly formatted, after reformatting it:

```
<digitizer id="1" integrated="true" csrmusttouch="" falsehardprox="true" physidcsrs="false"  pnpid="49154" kind="MULTI_TOUCH" maxcsrs="10">
    <monitor left="0" top="0" right="1920" bottom="1080"/>
    <properties>
        <property name="x" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="621.7457275" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010030" guid="{598A6A8F-52C0-4BA0-93AF-AF357411A561}" />
        <property name="y" logmin="0" logmax="16383" res="983.9639893" unit="cm" hidusage="0x00010031" guid="{B53F9F75-04E0-4498-A7EE-C30DBB5A9011}" />
        <property name="status" logmin="0" logmax="15" res="0" unit="DEFAULT" hidusage="0x000d0042, 0x000d003c, 0x000d0044" guid="{6E0E07BF-AFE7-4CF7-87D1-AF6446208418}" />
        <property name="time" logmin="0" logmax="2147483647" res="1" unit="DEFAULT" guid="{436510C5-FED3-45D1-8B76-71D3EA7A829D}" />
        <property name="contactid" logmin="0" logmax="31" res="1.861861944" unit="cm" hidusage="0x000d0051" guid="{02585B91-049B-4750-9615-DF8948AB3C9C}" />
```

You can easily parse it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('data.xml') as raw_resuls:
    results = BeautifulSoup(raw_resuls, 'lxml')

for element in results.find_all("properties"):
    for property_tag in element.find_all("property"):
        print(property_tag['res'])
```

Output:

```
621.7457275
983.9639893
0
1
1.861861944
```

You can find more info about parsing attribute values from xml in [the tutorial where the code is from.](https://newbedev.com/how-to-get-an-attribute-value-using-beautifulsoup-and-python)

Edit: Note that I slightly modified the code to fit your question.